# cortex-m7 cant use swd r/w core register

Tags: cpu-registers, cortex-m, swd

I try to use software to simulate swd on a cortex-m7 development board, and burn the bootloader file of another cortex-m7 development board. Most of the time it works, but occasionally it goes wrong, which I suspect has something to do with my not stopping the core. When I try to rewrite DHCSR and other core registers through DAP, check fail, the return ack val is 0b111, and the phenomenon is the same when I try to access abnormal addresses. Accessing other addresses is ok.

It is suspected that it is related to the current security mode, but the relevant register configuration was not found. Core register DHCSR is accessible by command on another development board. Wondering if there is a related configuration mode that allows me to access its arm core registers via swd. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/MarkDing/swd_programing_sram， 
I solve it.When unlocking the AP, the CSW should be written as 0x23000002, but I mistakenly wrote it as 0x80000012. After modification, it can normally access the kernel registers of another development board